# 5 column item listing is really bad in mobile how can i fix this?

Tags: css

I have a business directory here it is https://www.endustri.io/firma/

I am listing the categories in five columns. When i looked the mobile i was shocked. Really bad looking. How can fix this?
I want to see mobile version look like desktop, or better than this time.

Here is my css code

```
#native {
  
  width: 100%;
  height: min-content; /*your fixed height*/
  display: inline-block; /*necessary*/
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
       -moz-column-count: 5;
            column-count: 5;
  
  
}
```

This is desktop
[image]

And this is mobile
[image]

Comment: Change the column count on smaller screens using [@media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: You say: 'I want to see mobile version look like desktop,'. Could you describe a bit more what you want it to look like on narrower viewports? As there just isn't room for 5 columns without the text going vertical you either have to cut down the number of columns (I would suggest to just 1), make the user scroll horizontally or make the type face tiny. Neither of the last two would be very easy to use!

Comment: Note: no browser has needed those vendor prefixes in many, many years.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve it by changing `column-count` on mobile devices to, for example, 2. You can target mobile devices with `@media screen` of specific range:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #native {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Always write CSS in Mobile First Methodology: And your solution for this question is below**

```
#native {
  width: 100%;
  height: min-content; /*your fixed height*/
  display: inline-block; /*necessary*/
  -webkit-column-count: 1;
  -moz-column-count: 1;
  column-count: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #native {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  #native {
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  #native {
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    column-count: 5;
  }
}
```